# Postgres: Statistical functions on date time intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to run some statistical analysis on intervals i.e. difference between two datetime fields in a table.

According to the aggregate function documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html). The aggregate 
functions for `MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG` etc i.e. general aggregate functions accept arguments for date-time and interval fields.

However for more advanced statistical functions like `stddev_pop`, `var_pop`, `var_sam` and `std_samp` the input supported seem to be numeric or similar only. Although the documentation suggests there is no difference between the two types of functions

> ... (These are separated out merely to avoid cluttering the listing of
>   more-commonly-used aggregates.)...

Is there any easy way to calculate these parameters ? and why is interval type as argument not supported ? These types of statistical aggregate functions are unit invariant ?

P.S. I am not sure I can extract epoch and use it, as some values may be negative.

Comment: The difference between two datetime fields strikes me as being numeric.

Comment: Thats what I also thought, however the difference is the date type interval, and these functions do not take interval inputs, avg does though Which does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @DanBracuk the difference between two `timestamps` is an `interval`

Comment: _I am not sure I can extract epoch and use it, as some values may be negative._ What is the problem with negative values? If you do not want them why can't you get the absolute value?

Comment: Well I am not sure how they work for postgresql intervals. I know for absolute time stamp it is the difference between Unix epoch and the time given. But `interval` is a relative time between two dates already how can you "extract" epoch or calculate the difference between what is already a difference ? . If I have to apply this directly on the timestamp fields, Will I have to take care of negative time periods case for dates before 1970 as well ?

Comment: The problem here with manually working out the standard deviation is that at some point you have to multiply an interval by an interval, and PostgreSQL doesn't support that. So I think you're going to have to first reduce an interval to something simpler: hours, minutes, or seconds, for example.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' I understand. Normally documentation is very clear. Perhaps this should be added there somewhere. 
P.S. If you add this as an answer I can select for future users :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in a comment, to work out sample standard deviation manually, at some point you multiply an interval by an interval. PostgreSQL doesn't support that.

To work around that issue, reduce the interval to hours or minutes or seconds (or whatever). This turns out to be a lot simpler than working out the calculation manually, and it suggests why PostgreSQL doesn't support this kind of calculation out of the box.

First, a function from the [PostgreSQL general mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAHsw44-mWjPm%3D1WaeuU35BAZi1ouoyDngTwQpzaKeDRA1oCwww%40mail.gmail.com)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION interval_to_seconds(interval)
RETURNS double precision AS $$
    SELECT (extract(days from $1) * 86400)
         + (extract(hours from $1) * 3600)
         + (extract(minutes from $1) * 60)
         + extract(seconds from $1);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Now we can take the standard deviation of a simple set of intervals.

```
with intervals (i) as (
  values (interval '1 hour'), (interval '2 hour'), (interval '3 hour'), 
         (interval '4 hour'), (interval '5 hour') 
)
, intervals_as_seconds as (
  select interval_to_seconds(i) as seconds
  from intervals
)
select stddev(seconds), stddev(seconds)/60
from intervals_as_seconds
```

```
in_sec             in_min
double precision   double precision
--
5692.09978830308   94.8683298050514
```

You can verify the results however you like.

Now let's say you wanted hour granularity instead of seconds. Clearly, the choice of granularity is highly application dependent. You might define another function, `interval_to_hours(interval)`. You can use a very similar query to calculate the standard deviation.

```
with intervals (i) as (
  values (interval '1 hour'), (interval '2 hour'), (interval '3 hour'), 
         (interval '4 hour'), (interval '5 hour') 
)
, intervals_as_hours as (
  select interval_to_hours(i) as hours
  from intervals
)
select stddev(hours) as stddev_in_hrs
from intervals_as_hours
```

```
stddev_in_hrs
double precision
--
1.58113883008419
```

The value for standard deviation in hours is clearly different from the value in minutes or in seconds. But they measure exactly the same thing. The point is that the "right" answer depends on the granularity (units) you want to use, and there are a lot of choices. (From microseconds to centuries, I imagine.)

Also, consider this statement.

```
select interval_to_hours(interval '45 minutes')
```

```
interval_to_hours
double precision
--
0
```

Is that the right answer? You can't say; the right answer is application-dependent. I can imagine applications that would want 45 minutes to be considered as 1 hour. I can also imagine applications that would want 45 minutes to be considered as 1 hour for *some* calculations, and as 0 hours for *other* calculations.

And think about this question. How many seconds are in a month? The expression `select interval '1' month;` is valid; the number of seconds depends on how many days are in the month.

And I think *that's* why PostgreSQL doesn't support this kind of calculation out of the box. The right way to do it with interval arguments is too application-dependent.

**Later . . .**

I found this discussion on one of the PostgreSQL mailing lists.

[No stddev() for interval?](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/37ed240d0605200814y5dfbd443s9d6938dbf3bd9aa4%40mail.gmail.com)

Comment: There is no need to write your own `interval_to_seconds()`. This can be done using `extract(epoch from ...)`

Comment: thx for the detailed explanation. The mailing list thread had come on google search, however I was not sure why such a hack seemed necessary then. The different units make values varying especially since time does not standard decimal conversion. While assuming a default of say seconds is possible i guess, it may not desirable or sensible to do so.

Comment: I can't test it, but you might try to calculate the result as seconds again, I use thison Teradata: `stddev(seconds) * interval '0000 00:00:00'  second`